# Compare the content of a dataframe with a cell value in other and replace the value matched in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes,

`df1 =`

| Countries description | Continents | values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C0001 also called America, | America | 21tr |
| C0004 and C0003 are neighbhors | Europe | 504 bn |
| on advancing C0005 with C0001.security | Europe | 600bn |
| C0002, the smallest continent | Australi | 1.7tr |

`df2 =`

| Countries | Id |
| --- | --- |
| US | C0001 |
| Australia | C0002 |
| Finland | C0003 |
| Norway | C0004 |
| Japan | C0005 |

df1 has columns Countries descriptions but instead of their actual names, codes are given.
df2 has countries with their codes.

I want to replace the countries Code(like C0001, C0002) with their Names in the df1, like this:

`df1 =`

| Countries description | Continents | values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US also called America, some.. | America | 21tr |
| Norway and Finland are neighbhors | Europe | 504 bn |
| on advancing Japan with US.security | Europe | 600bn |
| Australia, the smallest continent | Austral | 1.7tr |

I tried with the Pandas merge method but that didnt work:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['Countries'], how='left')
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to approach it with [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) :

```
d = dict(zip(df2["Id"], df2["Countries"]))
​
df1["Countries description"] = df1["Countries description"].replace(d, regex=True)
```

Output :
​

```
print(df1)
                 Countries description Continents  values
0              US also called America,    America    21tr
1    Norway and Finland are neighbhors     Europe  504 bn
2  on advancing Japan with US.security     Europe   600bn
3    Australia, the smallest continent   Australi   1.7tr
```